# Change Password Entry text to asterisk(*) instead of dots(.) in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on xamarin.forms and I've a password entry field,which displaying the text in dot(.) format but I want the password text to be shown in asterisk(*).Is there any way to change the password text from dot(.) to asterisk.

The Password entry is like this:

```
<Entry x:Name="Password" Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="True" />
```

I've been trying to find a way to do this but I'm unable to.Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change password masking character in Xamarin forms - Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942722/how-to-change-password-masking-character-in-xamarin-forms-entry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to change password masking character in Xamarin forms - Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942722/how-to-change-password-masking-character-in-xamarin-forms-entry)

It seems to be a duplicate question.

(Since I don't have enough reputation for comment, I had to write a answer)

Comment: If you find something that is a duplicate you can always flag it and people with enough reputation would be able to find it, anyway good work! Upvote from my side!