# How can I mask characters of a password as I type them in xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

As the title states, I want to be able to type the password and after I am done typing each character the mask is generated, to be more specific. If I was typing and the first letter I typed was `f` then when I went to type the second letter of `o` then the `f` would become a `*` or the masked character of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

This seems to be duplicate with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509932/change-password-entry-text-to-asterisk-instead-of-dots-in-xamarin-forms).It turns out that this can be either achieved via `Converter` or `Custom Renderer` in Xamarin.

**Solution 2**

This nuget package: **Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfMaskedEdit** is a best fit for your requirement.You could set `masked character` of your choice via
`PasswordChar="*"` and don't forget to set `EnablePasswordDelay="True"`.

```
<syncfusion:SfMaskedEdit x:Name="maskedEdit"  PasswordChar="*"  EnablePasswordDelay="True"/>
```

[Reference link](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/masked-entry/show-password-character).