# masking password character in Xamarin forms is not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I would like to partially mask the password field from dots to asterisk. I tried using a converter but it doesn't work. What is the best way to achieve this in xamarin forms.

```
     <Entry IsPassword="True"
            Placeholder="password"
            Text="{Binding Password.Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource 
            MaskedPasswordConverter}}"
            MaxLength="6">

     public class MaskedPasswordConverter : IValueConverter
     {

       private string _value;
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo 
       culture)
       {
         var str = (value ?? "").ToString();
         _value = str;
         var maskedStr = "";
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Length > 2)
         {
            var domainStr = str.IndexOf('@');
            var lengthOfMask = domainStr - 2;

            maskedStr = str.Substring(0, 2) + new string('*', lengthOfMask) + 
            str.Substring(domainStr);
         }
         return maskedStr;
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
       CultureInfo culture)
       {
         return value;
       }
    }
```

Comment: you need to use a custom renderer

Comment: if you try with IsPassword = "False"? you are making your own mask

Comment: @AlexanderRojas It is still not working

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use behaviors for this. 
You can find out more about Xamarin forms behaviors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating)

More examples [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IValueConverter to mask partial password using asterisk, I think you can set binding mode as OneWay, then please confirm that there is @ character in your Password.

I suggest you can use this way to mask email, don't mask password, but you still want to do ,this is the sample that you can take a look:

```
 <Entry
            MaxLength="6"
            Placeholder="password"
            Text="{Binding password, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource converter1}}" />

public partial class Page24 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _password;
    public string password
    {
        get
        { return _password; }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("password");               
        }
    }
    public Page24()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        password = "123@56";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;      
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

IValueConverter:

```
public class Passwordconverter : IValueConverter
{      
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = (value ?? "").ToString();

        var maskedStr = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Length > 2)
        {
            var domainStr = str.IndexOf('@');
            var lengthOfMask = domainStr - 2;

            maskedStr = str.Substring(0, 2) + new string('*', lengthOfMask) + str.Substring(domainStr);
        }
        return maskedStr;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

But I still suggest you can use custom render to mask your password using asterisk, this is the sample about this, you can take a look:

[How to change password masking character in Xamarin forms - Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942722/how-to-change-password-masking-character-in-xamarin-forms-entry?rq=1)